# Removing a folder from DDMS?

Tags: android, eclipse, ddms

In the Eclipse DDMS's file explorer, I've unwanted folders like **temp, deleted_items and etc** created by my own. I want to remove them from file explorer.

I know how to remove files from explorer.  I can remove the files from folders also. In that same time, i can't remove the folder from explorer.

Why it's not working with same method of removing files. Anyone guide me?

Comment: Are these system folders, or folders you created?  Unless you have rooted your device, you might not have rights to the folder.

Comment: @Jbecwar : No it's by my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from DDMS file explorer you can't remove folder. You can only remove files from it, If you want to remove it, then you should try either adb shell or by programatically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the folders can't be deleted from DDSM though removing files is fine. Have to go to "adb shell" and call "rmdir "